# how to sort wss web pages

Tags: sharepoint, service, wss

I've been using WSS 2.0 for ao long but i don't know how to sort a web page after i created. Ex. After i created a subsite, i create my web pages but the problem is that sharepoint sorts the pages alphabetically and i need to assign my own order.

Someone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a column to define your sort order (just a number field).

Then create a view to order by your sort order column.